# Kotlin: Scheduled notification not working. Unsure why

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications

I've been trying to schedule a notification for a certain time but the notification won't fire at that time. I'm really unsure as to why. Hope someone can point me in the right direciton.

This is the receiver class:

```
class ReminderReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        try {
            val reminderTitle = intent?.getStringExtra("REMINDER_TITLE")
            val reminderBody = intent?.getStringExtra("REMINDER_BODY")
            val notificationDate = intent?.getStringExtra("NOTIFICATION_DATE")

            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            val notificationDateAsCalendar = sdf.parse(notificationDate!!)
            ReminderUtils.generateReminderNotification(context!!, reminderTitle!!, reminderBody!!, notificationDateAsCalendar!!)
        } catch(e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```

This is the utils class that should fire the notification:

```
class ReminderUtils {
    companion object {
        fun generateReminderNotification(context: Context,
            notificationTitle: String,
            notificationBody: String,
            notificationDate: Date
        ) {
            val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, App.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_REMINDER_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_reminder)
                .setContentTitle("Reminder")
                .setContentText("rrrr")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                .setVibrate(longArrayOf(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L))

            val resultIntent = Intent(context, ViewRemindersFragment::class.java)
            val taskStackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context)
            taskStackBuilder.addParentStack(ViewRemindersFragment::class.java)
            taskStackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent)

            val resultPendingIntent =
                taskStackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                )

            notification.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            notification.setAutoCancel(true)

            val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.notify(1111, notification.build())
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the fragment where it happens, inside an onClickListener:

```
        val addButton = view.button_add_reminder
        addButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val index = adapter.itemCount
            exampleList.add(Reminder("I have added a reminder at index $index", Date(2020, 0, 0)))
            adapter.notifyItemInserted(index)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            view.recycler_view_all_reminders.smoothScrollToPosition(exampleList.size)



            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9)
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2020)
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4)
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 12)
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM,Calendar.AM)


            val myIntent = Intent(context!!, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            myIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_TITLE", "Reminder");
            myIntent.putExtra("REMINDER_BODY", "Reminder Body");
            myIntent.putExtra("NOTIFICATION_DATE", calendar.toString());
            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context!!, 0, myIntent,0)

            val alarmManager = context!!.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
        })
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use **Hour of Day** then its 24 hour format .But after this you're telling calander that its AM/PM

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not receiving the notification.